# Time not updating correctly in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to add an update which sets the users last activity, at the moment it is just displaying 838:59:59 as the time in the mysql, and i am not quite sure why.

Here is the query i am using on each page to update it.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = ".time()." WHERE user_id = ".$user_id);
```

Any ideas why i would greatly appreciate

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of the `last_activity` column in your `users` table? Where is it "just displaying 838:59:59"?

Comment: Could you show us the structure of your table `users` (or at least the type of `last_activity` ?

Comment: Hi the type for last activity is just `time`

Comment: since time() returns a datestamp, i assume that your table data type is not varchar, text or integer... if you want to save the current time into a table with data type "date", use mysql's NOW() function: `UPDATE users SET last_activity=NOW() WHERE user_id='$user_id'`

Comment: I am trying to follow this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619451/php-last-log-in-script I have added everything there but it still does not work, no matter what datatype i use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = NOW() WHERE user_id = ".$user_id);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE user_id = ".$user_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the PHP solution, using UTC (GMT). Make sure you quote the date and other strings:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = '".gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' WHERE user_id = ".$user_id);
```

Here it is in local time:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET last_activity = '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."' WHERE user_id = ".$user_id);
```

You need to format the datetime into the proper format for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Really late on this but in case anyone else hits the issue, is userID a number in the example from original question. I made the opposite mistake once, put quote marks around an id that was a number and it took me an embarrassingly long amount of time to figure out why the logout timestamp would not update.