# PHP last_activity

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm coding a little website where users can login. Now I want to show the last activity from each user.

I add a row called `last_activity` as `INT` to my database. I found that one: [PHP Last log in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619451/php-last-log-in-script?answertab=votes#tab-top) and tried do it like that.

```php
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET last_activity = ".time()." WHERE id = ".$id."");
$result =  $statement->execute();

$state = $pdo->prepare("SELECT last_activity FROM users WHERE id = ".$id.", 0");
$result = $state->execute();
$activity = $state->fetch();
```

and to show

```php
echo relativeTime($activity);
```

> PDOStatement Error: PDOStatement::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 0' at line 1 )

And it shows whatever I do -> 50 years ago (from function `relativeTime`)

Comment: why do u have put `0` in the last query statement ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code should as below,
if you want use time() function instead mysql now() function u can use

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE users SET last_activity=:time WHERE id =:id");
$result =  $statement->execute
[
 ":time"=>time(),
 ":id"=>$id

]

);

$state = $pdo->prepare("SELECT last_activity FROM users WHERE 
in id  ( ?, 0");
$result = $state->execute(array($id));
$activity = $state->fetch();
```

Comment: Ask yourself why you would query for an id value of 0.